# How to define data used for DataGridview's column titles when using a list of objects in c#?

Tags: c#, object, datagridview, datasource

If you bind a DataGridview (winform) to a list of objects can you define which object property , a string, should be used for the column titles?

At the moment its using the properties names from the objects.

or is it possible to bind a separate datasource, another object, to the column headers for the purpose of defining these titles?

**UDATE**

Example

```
public string field_one{get;set;}
```

Shows up as "field_one" as the column header. I would like...

```
public string header_one{get;set;}
public string field_one{get;set;}

row.header_one="Friendly Header Title";
...........
List<row> rows = new List<row>();
```

So that the column header is "Friendly Header Title"

or to have a list of headers in a separate object, list of objects or other list based type.

example

```
class header...
{
...
 public string header_column_one{get;set;}
..
}

....

class row....
{
...
 public string field{get;set;}
..
}
```

.......
........

```
header.header_column_one="Nice Friendly Header"

List<row> rows = new List<row>();
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i'm reading your question right, you're asking about setting the titles for the columns.  DataGridViewColumn's HeaderText is your ticket.

MSDN Search "DataGridViewColumn"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.aspx

Comment: the DataGridView control pulls header names from a object by default it use the properties name which isn't friendly I would like to define a friendly name within the object as a property or use a separate object which defines them.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.headertext%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: Is that not what you're looking for?

Comment: Its my backup plan.  I would titles with the data in the object, the displayname attribute is what i am looking for *if* i can change it at runtime, however, my backup plan would be to write code that gets the titles out of the object and use the DataGridview's HeaderText Property. Thanks.

Comment: That's how i do it :-D  I'm tagging this question incase someone has some dark .Net Juju they share.

Comment: looks like its the easiest solution, so perhaps I will be using it after all.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the displayname attribute to customize the titles that will be displayed in the datagridview.

In your class, you can define each property like this

```
[DisplayName("Title")]
public string Something{get;set;}
```

Then "Title" will be shown as the header for this property in the grid. Using this way, you set the "default header" for all the datagrids in you app that are binded with a collection of this class.

**EDIT:**

Well, I think it will be difficult to change attributes in runtime, instead you can do something like

```
GridName.Columns["Something"].HeaderText = "Title"
```

**EDIT2:**

Ok, so you want to store the column name information in other class or object. Then you can try something like this

```
public static void ChangeHeaders(DataGridView dataGrid, Dictionary<String, String> data)
        {
            if (data == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            Dictionary<string, string>.Enumerator enumerator = data.GetEnumerator();
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                try
                {
                    dataGrid.Columns[enumerator.Current.Key].HeaderText = enumerator.Current.Value;
                }
                catch (NullReferenceException e)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("The column " + enumerator.Current.Key + " does not exist");
                }
            }
        }
```

This function receives a datagridview object, and a dictionary of strings/strings. The key of the dictionary is the name of the property, and the value is the text you want in the header. Construct the dictionary, call the function and the work is done.

Comment: that's nice, however, would it be possible to set this at runtime. I have also edited my question with example.

Comment: or change DisplayName attribute programmatically.

Comment: That was my backup plan. That's a really nice bit of code. Thanks

Comment: public static void ChangeHeaders(*ref* DataGridView dataGrid, Dictionary<String, String> data) ???